# Creating cocoa touch framework with objective c paypal

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods

Im creating cocoa touch framework for cocoa pod.In here im using paypal library.I download all files(paypal) and copy to may library folder.Paypal sdk still having objective c files.Also im creating swift project.In that case i can't add bridging header file to my cocoa touch framework project.Also i put that all header to public section.Still doesn't work.Whwn i remove all files from compile sources,It's build.But when i upload it to cocoa pod its giving error ' error: use of unresolved identifier 'PayPalMobile''

any one have idea